# nodejs couchbase install failure

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, couchbase, node-gyp

I have installed multiple packages like Express, Joi, Fastify without any issue. But when I try to install couchbase package using npm, it's always failing. Please find below the log.

```
> couchbase@2.6.10 install C:\Users\JInbaraj\Documents\VSCode_Projects\Node-js\Express\node_modules\couchbase
> prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=12.14.1 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

C:\Users\JInbaraj\Documents\VSCode_Projects\Node-js\Express\node_modules\couchbase>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "D:\node-v12.14.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "D:\node-v12.14.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "D:\\node-v12.14.1-win-x64\\node.exe" "D:\\node-v12.14.1-win-x64\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\JInbaraj\Documents\VSCode_Projects\Node-js\Express\node_modules\couchbase
gyp ERR! node -v v12.14.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
npm WARN Express@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN Express@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 7
npm ERR! couchbase@2.6.10 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 7
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the couchbase@2.6.10 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JInbaraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-14T10_42_00_899Z-debug.log
```

I am using a stable Node JS release. I have tried to reinstall the Node JS. I have tried to reinstall Python 2.7, windows build-essentials and also tried visual studio 2015 tools after referring this [link](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/03/27/node-gyp-windows/), but all in vain.

Any advice?

Comment: Did node-gyp installed successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the issue is fixed!

**Visual studio build tools** were shown installed successfully when installed using **npm** command (I have even tried installing multiple times using **npm**). Later, I used **Visual studio installer** and selected **Visual studio build tools 2017** to verify the install. To verify the install, I have tried the *Repair* option and to my surprise, it was just downloaded partially and it resumed from there. Waited for sometime to complete the download and install. Then restarted the PC and tried `npm i couchbase`... It worked!